# Using variables when getting all parent nodes recursively

Tags: mysql, prestashop, recursive-query

I try getting all parent categories for each category in select using the following query:

```
select @c := c.id_category,c.id_parent,
(SELECT 
      GROUP_CONCAT( @r := (
        SELECT  c1.id_parent
        FROM    ps_category c1 
        WHERE   c1.id_category = @r
        )) AS parent

FROM    (
        SELECT  @r := @c
        ) vars,
        ps_category  c2
        where @r<>0)  p
from   ps_category  c
join (select @c:=0) tmp
```

I expect to get something like this:
`id_category_id; id_parent; p 
1; 0; 0
2; 1; 1,0
3; 1; 1,0
4; 2; 2,1,0
...`
but it seems that something not working with initialisation of `@r` with `@c` , what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

```
  SELECT 
        @c:=c.id_category,
        c.id_parent,
        (SELECT 
                GROUP_CONCAT(@r:=(SELECT 
                                c1.id_parent
                            FROM
                                ps_category c1
                            WHERE
                                c1.id_category = @r)) AS parent
            FROM
                (SELECT @r:=@c) vars,(select @c:=0)Z, <!------- i had made changes at this line>
                ps_category c2
            WHERE
                @r <> 0) p
    FROM
        ps_category c
```

Try above query.

As mention in comment you are initialize variable `@c` at outer query ,and you are using that variable in inner query.So i had make that initialization to inner query.So automatically updated value will populate to outer query.

Hope this will help you.

I got below output
[image]
Whats your expected output?

Comment: Although this query may be the right answer, it would be a lot better if you explained what it does instead of just dumping it in your post.

Comment: @Shadow i had update my answer.And try to explain same.

Comment: That inner query where @c value is used is in the select list, not in the from clause. This way @c is always set to 0, which does not seem to be what the OP needs.

Comment: unfortunately not :(

Comment: can you try with this data 
CREATE TABLE `ps_category` (
  `id_category` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `id_parent` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) ;

INSERT INTO `ps_category` (`id_category`, `id_parent`) VALUES
(1, 0),
(2, 1),
(3, 1),
(4, 2),
(5, 2),
(6, 4);

Comment: @Shadow tried, but I expect to see all parents for each category, for example: 
for category_id 1 must be 0 
for category_id 2 must be 1,0
for category_id 3 must be 1,0
for category_id 4 must be 2,1,0
...

Answer (score 1):

I've sorted out this issue

```
  SELECT 
    @r:=c.id_category id_category,
    c.id_parent,
    (select GROUP_CONCAT(@r:=(SELECT 
                            c1.id_parent
                        FROM
                            ps_category c1
                        WHERE
                            c1.id_category = @r)) AS p
    from ps_category c2                        
    ) as parents

  FROM
    ps_category c, 
    (select @r:=0) Z

  group by c.id_category, c.id_parent
```